# div element not hiding after $_SESSION variable check during setInterval function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session-variables, setinterval

First post here (though long-time reader)!

I have created a setInterval function to check the $_SESSION['status'] variable and then hide/show certain  elements based on the $_SESSION variable's value.  (It's for a quiz site I'm creating for my class.)

I want it to work on any tabs that the user may have open.  So, let's say the user has 2 tabs open and is looking at two different pages on the site.  When the user begins to take a quiz on tab A, tab B's setInterval function should see that the $_SESSION['status'] variable has changed and show/hide the relevant  elements (to prevent the students from reading pages on the site during a quiz).  When I take a quiz on tab A, tab A hides/shows the correct information.  However, tab B stays the same until I refresh the page and then it does the correct thing.

How can I get tab B to change on its own without refreshing?

If it matters, $_SESSION['status'] = -1 when browsing and then a value of 0 or above when taking a quiz.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function check_login()
{
    if ("<?php echo $_SESSION['status']; ?>" >= '0')
        {
        $("#pagecontainer").hide();
        $("#quiz_msg").show();
        }

    else
        {
        $("#pagecontainer").show();
        $("#quiz_msg").hide();
        }
}

window.setInterval(check_login, 1000);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript function will contain the value of the session variable *at the point in time the page is loaded*.

Javascript doesn't have direct access to php script or server variables because javascript runs on the client, not the server.

To make this work, you'd need to use ajax calls to check the session variable or use websockets if you want to get fancy.

Comment: The italicized part above really gave me the key insight.

Answer (score 1):

this code will only work if the javascript is placed somewhere in the html, I guess it is because the  tags enclosing it. the code works the first time but then halts, so here is what you need to do:

1. Create a new php file named get_status.php (or similar) with the following contents:

   echo $_SESSION['status'];
2. Now replace your javascript code with this:

   $(document).ready(function () {

   ```
   function check_login() {

       var status = 0;

       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "get_status.php"
       }).done(function (msg) {
           status = msg;
           if (status >= 0) {
               $("#pagecontainer").hide();
               $("#quiz_msg").show();
           } else {
               $("#pagecontainer").show();
               $("#quiz_msg").hide();
           }
       });


   }

   window.setInterval(check_login, 1000);
   ```

   });

And that should be it :)

Comment: I didn't understand your code when you posted it, because I'm new to ajax.  But after some research I ended up using code very similar to yours.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know, you can't put PHP code in Javascript code, because first one are server language, and the second one, are client language, so they are executed in different times.

I recommend you to write the SESSION data on HTML field, with PHP, and read it with Javascript, using class selectors, or id selectors.